# How To Drop Temporary SP If Exists in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

My Question is simple! How to Drop a Temporary Stored Procedure If Exists ? This is because while I create a Temporary SP in a script, it throws error like 'There is already an object named '#sp_name' in the database' while i run the Second time. I dont want to show this message to users. 
        Please help me. Your solution is Highly appereciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The temp procs are dropped in the same way as permanent procs are dropped. 
Please see the code below:

```
-- Create test temp. proc
CREATE PROC #tempMyProc as
Begin
 print 'Temp proc'
END
GO
-- Drop the above proc
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempMyProc') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROC #tempMyProc
END
```

Comment: Thanks. It Works. Thank You Ram. I think All Temp SP stored in tempdb Databases. Is that so ? Please explain me.

Comment: You are welcome!...yes all the temporary objects (tables, procs) created with # sign will be created automatically in tempDB. Now there are other types in temp objects called global temp objects (created by using ## in the front). Even these are created in tempDB.

Comment: It is important to use IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempMyProc') IS NOT NULL
here. I had a code generator using IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempMyProc') > 0 and this code fails under SQL Server 2012 because OBJECT_ID becomes negative.

Answer (score 0):

NOT 2005 but with modern SQL server you can do:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  #TestTempSP;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'baz')
DROP PROCEDURE baz
```

Comment: Hi Tom! I tried your Code. Since It is Temporary Sp, it fails the If Condition.It wont Select the SP. Hence it wont Drop the Procedure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by Temporary? How are you creating it?

Comment: Ya! Temporary Stored Procedures means the Stored Procedures exists with in a session. Usually it is expressed as # followed by SP Name.Please refer msdn sites for further information.