# TSQL Temporary Procedure: There is already an object named

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temporary

A similar question has been answered, but only for temporary tables.

I want to use a temporary stored procedure, as per

```
-- test if folder exists, else create it
create procedure #mycheckcreatefolder
(
@rootfolder NVARCHAR(MAX),
@subfolder NVARCHAR (MAX)
)
as
BEGIN
      declare @full_path as NVARCHAR(MAX)
      declare @folder_exists as int
      declare @file_results table
      (file_exists int, file_is_a_directory int, parent_directory_exists int)
      select @full_path = @rootfolder + @subfolder

      insert into @file_results
      (file_exists, file_is_a_directory, parent_directory_exists)
      exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist @full_path

      select @folder_exists = file_is_a_directory
      from @file_results

      --script to create directory        
      if @folder_exists = 0
       begin
          print 'Directory does not exist, creating new one'
          EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @full_path
          print @full_path +  'created on' + @@servername
       end       
      else
        print 'Directory already exists'
END;
GO

-- use the stored procedure
```

but when I execute the query repeatedly I get

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure #mycheckcreatefolder, Line 30
There is already an object named '#mycheckcreatefolder' in the database.
```

Line 30 is the "print 'Directory already exists'".

I have removed all code below that, the error still pops up.

Also adding

```
drop procedure #mycheckcreatefolder
```

at the end does not help, as does a conditional drop in the beginning, since then I get the error that the "create procedure" needs to be the first instruction.

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Drop Temporary SP If Exists in Sql Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569655/how-to-drop-temporary-sp-if-exists-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#sp_today') is not null drop proc #sp_today;
go

create proc #sp_today as
   select getdate() as dt;
```

You should search for it in `tempdb`, not in current db

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mycheckcreatefolder') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.#mycheckcreatefolder
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.#mycheckcreatefolder
AS
    PRINT 'test';
```

Comment: Same result :) Looks like the temp procedure is a) undeletable and b) stays in the scope of the query window, so new window fixes the problem.

Comment: What I do not understand: I had a similar drop in the beginning beforehand, there I got the message that "create procedure needs to be the first instruction".

Comment: If you got such an error, you did not put GO before CREATE PROC and execute all in one batch

Answer (score 0):

The modern version in NEWER SQL Server versions can be like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS #TestTempSP;
```